# Parse JSON Array in Scala

Tags: arrays, json, scala, playframework

I have this jsArray (json Array) and I am using `import play.api.libs.json._` library.

```
[{”device”:”Samsung S8”,”android”:true},
{”device”:”iPhone 8”,”android”:false},
{”device”:”MacBook Air Pro”,”android”:false},
{”device”:”Dell XPS”,”android”:false}]
```

I want to traverse through this json array in Scala. This array is assigned to `var dependency`. I want to get the device names which are android. How do I do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
val jsonString: String = "[{\"device\":\"Samsung S8\",\"android\":true {\"device\":\"iPhone8\",\"android\":false}, {\"device\":\"MacBook Air Pro\",\"android\":false},{\"device\":\"Dell XPS\",\"android\":false}]"
val jsonList: List[JsValue] = Json.parse(jsonString).as[List[JsValue]]
val filteredList: List[JsValue] = jsonList.filter(json => (json \ "android").as[Boolean])
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This is what I needed!

Comment: What import needs to be done for the line Json.parse(jsonString).as[List[JsValue]]

Comment: The library is mentioned in the question